# are mongoid insert and update operations buffered?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Facing a rare issue whereby there seems to be stale data read in the after_save call of the object being saved.

Mongoid v7.0.13

Looking at the [mongoid source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blame/v7.0.13/lib/mongoid/persistable/updatable.rb#L132), the update call should have already been made before after_save callbacks.

Is there a chance for there to be some sort of buffer queue for mongoid/mongo, whereby the update call is not immediately processed?